# How can I output an "&" in RoR without getting "&amp;"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Controller code:

```
class HelpController<ApplicationController
   def index
      @url = "https://example.com/auth?user_id=1234&redirect_to=http://google.ru"
   end
end
```

View code:

```
<script>location.href='<%=@url%>';</script>
```

And it redirects to THIS:

```
example.com/auth?user_id=1234&amp;redirect_to=http://google.ru
```

This:
http://example.com/auth?user_id=1234 **& amp;** redirect_to=http://google.ru
(without spaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 3, you can call the .html_safe method to tell rails that you have verified the content is safe to send unescaped.

See http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/ for an explanation of the motivation for the default escaping behavior.

The idiom is reversed from older versions of rails, where you had to explicitly call .h (.html_escape).

Comment: I thought it called "safe_html" =D

Answer (score 1):

No Ruby expert, but I think escaping is the default behavior. You have to force it to output as an unescaped string by wrapping the thing in `raw()`.